# Continue Code In Debugger After Exception

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Is it possible in the Visual Studio Debugger to continue the execution of code after a runtime exception is thrown? (After fixing the cause of the exception)

For example.

If a `FileNotFound` exception is thrown, is it possible to go create the file and then backup and try to continue execution of the code again without having to restart the entire process?

This specifically applies to the .NET Framework, but more generally about Visual Studio in general

Answer (score 0):

The program resumes execution when the exception is caught somewhere by a "catch" block. Catching exceptions is explained later. You can throw any type of exception from your code, as long as your method signature declares it. You can also make up your own exceptions.

In your case, the link below might help you in solving your problem:
[Manage exceptions with the debugger in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Right about the try catch blocks, but im talking about in the debugger itself, where no try catch block is present. Thanks!